# Extracting data from MYSQL VIEW table to Rstudio

Tags: r, rmysql

Hi i am trying to get data from mysql table and VIEW table to R studio,fetching data from normal table got excecuted but for VIEW table i am unable to fetch data.
 below is the code to fetch data from VIEW.

```
conn=dbConnect(MySQL(),user="userid",password="pwd",dbname="db_name",host="localhost")

    view1 = dbSendQuery(conn, "select * from `processed_table_view` WHERE Date BETWEEN '2017-11-15' AND '2017-12-15' ")

    processed_view <- fetch(view1, n = -1) 

    dbClearResult(view1)

    dbDisconnect(conn)
```

i am getting the below error.

```
"Warning message:
  In fetch(RTU1, n = -1) : error while fetching rows"
```

any modification in above code required to get data from table VIEW.
Thanks in advance